# Elasticsearch unlimited size

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I am listening a traffic and inserting these traffic's data to elasticsearch continually.
And I want to search these datas with my python script.

Here is small part of my python code,

```
     test = es.search(
     index="argus_data",
     body=dict(query=search_body["query"],
                size= "1000") # I want to do this "unlimited"
  )

  pprint(test)
```

I dont know what is my size because I have new data continually.
how to manage this situation please help me to solve this issue,Thanks.

Answer (score 21):

You can do it this way:

```
test=es.search(index=['test'],doc_type=['test'],size=1000, from_=0)
```

Then change `from_` gradually until you get all of the data.

> from_ – Starting offset (default: 0)
>   [Elasticsearch-Py API Documentation](http://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html)

Answer (score 8):

First get number of hits by using test['hits']['total'] into a variable, then pass it to size.

You have to use the query two times. The first time you use it to get number of hits(don't pass size argument).

```
test=es.search(index=['test'],doc_type=['test'])
size=test['hits']['total']
```

Second time use the query along with size

```
test=es.search(index=['test'],doc_type=['test'],"size":size)
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer helped me on getting the total count!  However, the second command did not work, I still got the error: 'Result window is too large, from + size must be less than or equal to: [10000] but was [...].

Answer (score 1):

You will get error if there will be more than 10000 observation..

Answer (score 0):

```
# The solution is to calculate the number of documents you have 

test=es.search(index=['indexname'])
size=test['hits']['total']

#size['value'] is the size of your data

# The solution is to calculate the number of documents you have then you make your query based on that size 

res = es.search(index="indexname", body={'size' : size['value'],"query": {"match_all": {}}})``

# you can loop into your data like this 

while i<size['value']:
    print(res['hits']['hits'][i]['_source']['fieldname'])
    i=i+1
```